# Addition and subtraction in digital electronics

Tags: digital-logic, math

Why is it that addition of the 2's complement is an efficient method of subtracting? Does this simplify the circuit?

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense.  However, A - B and A + (-B) are the same thing.  Depending on the numbering system, the latter may be easier to realize in gates.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Sir, I am trying to know what makes the latter easy to realize in terms of gates.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that it is? I smell some possible confusion here with the concept of 2's complement as a way of representing negative values

Comment: PrimeCzar: I suggest you provide more information about your thinking so we can actually help you. Otherwise the question might get closed.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough. Obviously it was not written by a native English speaker. I've taken the liberty of clarifying.

Comment: The way we were shown this in our intro digital logic course was by the instructor showing us how binary addition was similar to regular addition (with carries cascading into the next place). Then, the instructor showed us binary subtraction like regular longhand subtraction, and then showed how tedious it could get once you needed to borrow a number from a higher place value. That was his motivation to use A + (-B) instead of A - B. At which point, 2's complement was introduced. I think that's a decent reason in itself of why 2's complement is used, though it's not in the context of gates.

Answer (score 4):

As Olin pointed out in his comment, A - B and A + (-B) are the same thing, but note the latter actually uses addition.

So with 2's compliment, you only need one kind of circuit to do addition/subtraction, namely an adder (instead of an adder and a separate subtracter, plus the circuitry to switch the data bus back and forth between the two).

Taking the two's complement of a number involves first taking the 1's complement (toggling all of the bits, a trivial logic operation) and then adding one.  The latter seems to require a separate adder to perform that step before adding the two operands, but we can get by with just one adder circuit by setting the carry in lead of the first bit of the adder to high when doing subtraction, and low when doing addition.

```
An example:    5 - 3

    0101
-   0011
  ======
    0010

same as:

    0101
 +  1100  (1's complement of 0011)
 +     1  (carry-in)
  ======
    0010

Just the opposite:  3 - 5

    0011
-   0101
  ======
    1110

same as:

    0011
 +  1010  (1's complement of 0101)
 +     1  (carry-in)
  ======
    1110
```